# @IBAction of UIBarButtonItem not being called from UIToolbar inside generic cell of tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, generics, uitoolbar

the fact is I have created a generic cell that looks like this:

```
class GenericCell<T: ProtocolName>: UITableViewCell {

    // Properties ...

    var someThingINeed: T?

    private var toolbar: UIToolbar = {
        let toolbar = UIToolbar()
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
        toolbar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(didTapDone))
        let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(didTapCancel))

        cancelButton.tintColor = .red

        toolbar.setItems([cancelButton, flexibleSpace, doneButton], animated: false)

        return toolbar
    }()

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        if someThingINeed != nil {
            return toolbar
        }
        return nil
    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var canResignFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    // Functions ...

    @objc private func didTapDone() {
        // do something...
        resignFirstResponder()
    }

    @objc private func didTapCancel() {
        // do something...
        resignFirstResponder()
    }

}
```

So to call the cell input view, I execute this code from the `UITableViewController` that handles the table with the that type of cell:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

The result I get in the execution is both the `inputView` and the `inputAccessoryView` showing up but then, when I tap any of both `UIBarButtonItem` (Cancel or Done), the buttons seem to respond and receive the tap, but no action is called.

I think the reason might be either that a generic Swift class cannot act as a target for a `UIView` or that a generic Swift class cannot implement `@objc` functions.

I don't know what else to do, I have tried to add the cell as delegate of the `UIToolbar` and executing `toolbar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` and nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was that I forget to mark the `UIToolbar` as `lazy` so I couldn't use class properties and functions.

I don't know why Xcode didn't warn me about this... I think this could be reported.